# Art & Science of Java Chapter 4 Exercise 13

Tags: java

Should run a program that prints the largest, and second largest, but having problems getting the second value. Think my Boolean expression is wrong cause I keep getting 0 as tempSecond. Can you help?

```
/*
 * File: AddExamIntegers.java
 * --------------------
 * This program takes a list of integers until Sentinel, 
 * then prints the largest and second largest.
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class FindLargest extends ConsoleProgram {


    public void run() {
        println("This program takes a list of integers and then lists the largest and second largest");
        println("");
        println("Enter positive numbers using " + SENTINEL);
        println("to signal the end of the list");

        int tempHigh = 0;
        int tempSecond = 0;

        while (true)    {
            int value = readInt(": ");
            if (value == SENTINEL) break;
                if (tempHigh < value) {
                    tempHigh = value;
                    }
                if ((tempSecond < value) && (tempSecond > tempHigh)) {
                    tempSecond = value;
                    }
        }
        println("The largest value is " + tempHigh);
        println("The second largest value is " + tempSecond);
    }

    private static final int SENTINEL = 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (tempHigh < value)` then you have found a new high but your previous high is your new second.

Answer (score 3):

The second part of your latter if will never be true: `tempSecond > tempHigh`

Instead, do this:

```
        if(tempHigh < value)
        {
            tempHigh = value;
        }
        else if(tempSecond < value)
        {
            tempSecond = value;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks esaj, but I tried that. From what I can see, after tempHigh becomes the highest value, the first if statement will no longer be true at any time, and therefore, the tempSecond value will never have the chance to be reset.

Comment: @aldangerduncan: True, wasn't thinking straight, see my edited answer.